# AngularJS directives with async content

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, angularjs-directive

I'm generating a dynamic number of Google Charts tables after receiving the content through an ajax request and I wanted to apply an [accordion effect](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) on them. I wanted to know if I could do that with directives (since if I just code render the angular tags they won't get interpreted).

I don't need a code example, just a short answer to see if I should learn directives or if I should do it in a different way (I was thinking routeParams).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A directive is an equivalent of a jquery plugin, it should be use when you want to create a widget which manages some user interactions or a specific templating.

In your case it's a great idea, the directive could call a service which shall return the server datas and could manage all user interactions like open and close the accordion.

Before all, think about reusability.